# Custom block below body tag not showing

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, phtml

I add block .phtml file below `</body>` tag in my `/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Test" name="test" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"  after="before.body.end">
      </block>
    </referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>
```

but it's not showing the content inside .phtml file at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not possible to print any block inside </body>-- here --</html>, that means after </body> But you can print any block before body end. Try following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="before.body.end.custom" after="before.body.end">
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Form" name="testForm" template="VendorName_ModuleName::form.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```